# Phaser.js Get Created Graphic Points

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, phaser-framework

Good day,

Is there any way to get bounding points of a

created graphics in phaser once drawn in the canvas ?

```
var mask = game.add.graphics(0, 0); // point 0

mask.beginFill(0xFF3300);

mask.lineStyle(1, 0xffd900);
// draw a shape
mask.lineTo(0, 10); //point 1

mask.lineTo(10, 10); //point 2

mask.lineTo(10, 0); //point 3

mask.endFill();
```

Like i would get the point 0, point 1, point 2, point 3;

Im just wondering if there is a easy way to do it?

Comment: graphic shapes have the method `getBound`, it will return an object `Rectangle`, with that you should be able to calculate your four points.

Comment: @MamaWalter thanks, just check it and it works

Comment: It won't work, though, if the points don't form a rectangle, in which case you might be better off just adding every point to an array.